# Server 2003 Certificate Authority

Tags: windows-server-2003, certificate, ad-certificate-services

I have a Certificate Authority installed on Windows Server 2003 R2 Enterprise Edition, I am looking at auto enrollment.

When I go into the Certificate Authority mmc I cannot see Certificate Templates listed and I don't have Actions => New => Certificate Template to Issue as per [this ms technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739296%28WS.10%29.aspx)

All I can see is revoked, issued, pending and failed any ideas why?

Comment: I think I have found the problem running certutil -cainfo I noticed the ca has been setup as a  Stand-alone Root CA and I believe certificate templates are only available if you have an Enterprise root CA

Comment: You should post the comment as an answer so others can upvote it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I have found the problem running certutil -cainfo I noticed the ca has been setup as a Stand-alone Root CA and I believe certificate templates are only available if you have an Enterprise root CA